# Make a change to Javascript code that renumbers a list

Tags: javascript

I am unfamiliar with Javascript, but I would like to make a change to the following code. Currently, it renames macros in the program Keyboard Maestro in the format of 01), 02), etc. I would like it to simply use the format of a number followed by a space instead (i.e. 1 , 2 , etc.) I hope what I described makes sense. Thanks!

Part 1:

```
(function(inDesignMode) {
'use strict';

function dump(obj, desc) {
    console.log((desc ? desc + ": " : "") + JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t"));
}

var KMEditor = (function() {
    var _editorAppName = "Keyboard Maestro";
    var _editorApp;

    return {
        getEditorApp: function() {
            return _editorApp ? _editorApp : _editorApp = Application(_editorAppName);
        },

        getEditorAppName: function() {return _editorAppName;},

        getSelectedMacrosOrGroups: function() {
            return this.getEditorApp().selectedmacros();
        }
    };
})();

var KMEngine = (function() {
    var _engineApp;

    return {
        getAllMacrosSourceFileName: function() {
            return this.getAppSupportFolderName() + "Keyboard Maestro Macros.plist";
        },

        getAppSupportFolderName: function() {
            var app = Application.currentApplication();
            app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
            return app.pathTo('application support', { from: 'user domain' }) +
                "/Keyboard Maestro/";
        },

        getEngineAppName: function() {
            return "Keyboard Maestro Engine";
        },

        getEngineApp: function() {
            if (!_engineApp)
                _engineApp = Application(this.getEngineAppName());
            return _engineApp;
        },

        readPlistBinaryFile: function(path) {
            var data = $.NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path);
            return ObjC.deepUnwrap(
                $.NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithDataOptionsFormatError(
                    data, $.NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0, 0, null));
        },
    };
})();

function getMacrosInfo(selectedMacroUUIDs) {

    function getMacroName(macro) {
        if (macro.Name)
            return macro.Name;
        throw Error("Un-named Macro UUID: " + macro.UID);
    }

    function getMacroInfo(macro) {
        var info = {
            macroUUID: macro.UID,
            macroName: getMacroName(macro)
        };
        var matches = info.macroName.match(/^(\d\d)?(\))?(.*)/);
        if (!matches || matches.length != 4)
            throw Error("Could not parse macro name '" + info.macroName + "'");
        info.prefixNumber = matches[1] || "";
        info.macroNameNoPrefix = matches[3].trim();
        return info;
    }

    function reOrderResult(macrosInfo, selectedMacroUUIDs) {
        macrosInfo.macros = selectedMacroUUIDs.map(function(selectedMacroUUID) {
            var info = macrosInfo.macros.find(function(macroInfo) {
                return macroInfo.macroUUID === selectedMacroUUID;
            });
            if (!info)
                throw Error("Could not find macro information for UUID '" + selectedMacroUUID + "'");
            return info;
        });
    }

    // getMacrosInfo()
    var result = {
        macros: []
    };
    var macroGroup;
    var plist = KMEngine.readPlistBinaryFile(KMEngine.getAllMacrosSourceFileName());
    plist.MacroGroups.forEach(function(group) {
        if (group.Macros) {
            group.Macros.forEach(function(macro) {
                if (selectedMacroUUIDs.indexOf(macro.UID) >= 0) {
                    if (!result.groupUUID) {
                        macroGroup = group;
                        result.groupUUID = group.UID;
                        result.groupName = group.Name;
                        result.groupToggleMacroUID = group.ToggleMacroUID;
                    } else if (result.groupUUID !== group.UID) {
                        throw Error("Selected macros must all be from the same group");
                    }

                    result.macros.push(getMacroInfo(macro));
                }
            });
        }
    });

    reOrderResult(result, selectedMacroUUIDs);

    return result;
} // getMacrosInfo()

function execute() {
    var selectedMacroUUIDs = KMEditor.getSelectedMacrosOrGroups();
    if (!selectedMacroUUIDs || selectedMacroUUIDs.length < 2)
        throw Error("You must select two or more macros");

    var result = getMacrosInfo(selectedMacroUUIDs);
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}

if (inDesignMode) {
    return execute();
} else {
    try {
        return execute();
    } catch (e) {
        return "Error: " + e.message;
    }
}
```

})(false);

Part 2:

```
(function(inDesignMode, designModeParams) {
'use strict';

var _kme = Application("Keyboard Maestro Engine");
function getKMVariable(name, required) {
    var result = undefined;
    if (inDesignMode && designModeParams)
        result = designModeParams[name];
    if (result === undefined)
        result = _kme.getvariable(name);
    if (required && !result)
        throw Error("Variable '" + name + "' is empty");
    return result;
}

var _km = Application("Keyboard Maestro");

function execute() {
    var macroId = getKMVariable("palorg_MacroUUID", true);
    var newName = getKMVariable("palorg_NewMacroName", true);
    var macros = _km.macros.whose({id: {"=": macroId}});
    if (macros.length == 0)
        throw new Error("Macro '" + macroId + "' not found");
    var macro = macros[0];
    macro.name = newName;
    return "OK";
}

if (inDesignMode) {
    try {
        return execute();
    } catch (e) {
        return "Error on line: " + e.line + ": " + e.message;
    } finally {
        try {
            Application("Atom").activate();
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
} else {
    try {
        return execute();
    } catch (e) {
        return "Error: " + e.message;
    }
}
```

})(false);

Comment: So essentially you want the result from `getKMVariable` to be in the format that you describe? i.e. 01, 02 to 1, 2 etc.? What about the following indices? Is it 010 or just 10 at present?

Comment: Yes, from 01) → 1 . I only need it to go up to 9.

Comment: Can you also post an example of one of the `newName`?

Comment: It could be something like: 01)macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per clarifications obtained in your comment, this is what you need:

`01)macro` --> `1 macro`

To get that, you can try adding the following lines in `execute()` function in Part 2:

```
const regExp = /^0(.)\)/i; //Creates the regular expression
newName.replace(regex, '$1 '); //Replaces the match from the regex with a substring
macro.name = newName;
```

This is a regular expression substring replacement (more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). Here's the breakdown on what's being done.

The `^` symbol denotes that a substring is being searched from the *beginning* of the string.

The next `0` is just a literal search for a `0` at the beginning of the string.

The next `(` starts a *parenthesized submatch string* whose utility will be explained later.

The `.` indicates any *single* character.

The next `)` end the *parenthesized submatch string* started earlier.

The next `\)` is for searching a `)` literally which needs to be escaped with `\` since `)` has a special meaning of ending a *parenthesized submatch string* as mentioned above.

Now, the *parenthesized submatch string* is used so that after matching against the regular expression, the result can be used further to replace the matched string with. In this case,

`01)macro` will match `1` as the *parenthesized submatch string* since that's a single character after the leading 0 and before the `)`. This is used as `$1` in the replace function so that after matching `01)`, it's replaced with `1` (notice the extra space, as is required by the question).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply @Zoso. Where exactly should I paste your code in the `getKMVariable` function? I keep getting an error saying the `regex` variable can't be found.

Comment: @angds274 Oops, my bad. The change needs to go in the `execute()` function. I've edited my answer. Does that help now?

Comment: Still having trouble. :( Which line exactly in the `execute()` function should I add the change to? Do any of the old lines need to be deleted?

Comment: In the `execute()` function, start from the end of it. There's this line `return "OK";`, above that `macro.name = newName;`. This is the line that I mentioned in my solution. Just add the first 2 lines of my solution above this line.